# Could anyone recommend an Ubuntu mirror that does not do mirroring?

Tags: 12.04, server, apt

I have an Ubuntu server behind a very locked down environment. The only way I can talk to Internet is through an HTTP proxy server which uses whitelisting to only allow specific hosts.

Because of the above, `apt` uses a proxy to access my Ubuntu repository mirror. Two of the mirrors I've been using are occasionally doing HTTP temporary redirects to other servers for certain files. This is problematic for me since I am doing whitelisting. **Does anyone know of a stable Ubuntu mirror which does not do HTTP redirects?**

Comment: I think you're asking for the impossible. What should Server N do if it knows that package P (on N's disk) is obsolete, and is in the process of downloading package P's new version from Server Q. Server N cannot give you the old version of package P, and it does not have a complete copy of the updated P.

Comment: Why don't you use the default official server, which is what the mirrors mirror from? Or set up your own internal mirror, if you need things to be so locked down.

Answer (score 1):

@dobey recommended me to have a look at the default official server, `archive.ubuntu.com`. There's probably no official promise that it won't redirect, but I wrote a test script that downloaded ~600 MB of sampled Debian packages from the repository and made sure that not a single of those requests were redirected. The same test for my previous two mirrors failed the test.

I'll use `archive.ubuntu.com`. Thanks @dobey!